# How can I pretty format a JSON file, with all the correct indents and everything?

Tags: text-formatting, json

I have a JSON file on CentOS where all text is on the same line. How can I pretty format it with all the correct indents and everything?

Comment: Could you show us an example file? Does this need to be automatic? If not, just load it in a decent text editor and do it manually (in emacs, select everything and `M-X indent-selection`).

Comment: Have a look at `jq`. Also very handy if you want to process JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the package `yajl`, Yet Another JSON Library. On CentOS 7 it is located in the base repo, and is most probably already installed on the machine.

**To pretty-print a JSON file:**

```
json_reformat < myfile.json
```

**To verify that a file is in correct JSON syntax:**

```
json_verify < myfile.json
```

Comment: install with `sudo apt install yajl-tools` in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 15):

Use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) a very good JSON processor and from personal preference, its the best available in the market

for just pretty print, use

```
jq . file_name
```

Comment: The problem I currently have with jq, is that it is very liberal. I basically just want it to change whitespaces, but instead it changes things like 1.23e5 to 123000 and 0 to 0.0 and NaN to null and such things. Because of this I can't trust it anymore. It's not just a formatter it's also a sanitizer at the same time, which is not what I want right now.

Comment: @mxmlnkn It would not do this if you stored those values as strings.  If they are not strings, then I don't really see how it matters.

Comment: @Kusalananda Storing numbers as strings just feels wrong, even if it would only add two characters in JSON. I understand your confusion to some extent, JSON doesn't even discern between float and integers and doesn't even allow NaN for their "numbers". However, I had some (non JSON compliant, JSON-like) data and I had a very finicky reader for that data and all I wanted was to add and format whitespaces. All other changes may and did break something. `jq` just wasn't the right tool for that job. Using `sed` with some regex rules, worked just fine enough for me.

Comment: @mxmlnkn Well, if what you had wasn't JSON, with its own rules about data types etc., then you should obviously use some other parser for it.

Comment: @mxmlnkn In many cases storing numbers as either integers or strings may be big advantage or even requirement. Especially for money. IEEE 754's floats introduce rounding errors in a lot of situations.

Comment: @Kusalananda I agree with you regarding the `NaN` => `null` part, since `NaN` isn't valid JSON. The argument about numbers seems a more reasonable concern. The [JSON format](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) allows numbers with or without decimals, and with or without exponents.  JSON parsers can decide if they care to differentiate between "5.0" and "5".  Per the [ECMA standard](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-404/), "JSON is agnostic about the semantics of numbers", though it very well might matter to the end program whether it's "5.0" or "5".

Comment: @M.Justin I the _formatting_ of numbers matters, then you are actually talking about strings, not numbers, and should store the numbers as strings using the formatting that you require.

Comment: @Kusalananda Not according to a strict reading of the JSON format.  JSON doesn't define whether two different numerically equal numbers are the same or not; that's up to the client.  But I'll agree that representing it as a string is going to be the most cross-platform guaranteed way to handle it, since by default so many JSON parsers aren't going to distinguish between the two.

Comment: @M.Justin I'm not quite sure where it is you disagree with me. If you need to store a number in a particular format in a JSON document, store it as a string (since it is not really the number's numerical value you're interested in but its exact representation, which may carry meta-information such as precision etc.)

Answer (score 11):

If you don't want to install an additional package and have python available you can do:

```
python -m json.tool myfile.json
```

It also supports reading from STDIN

Answer (score 3):

Found 4 already available tools in my Gentoo system:

From package `dev-libs/json-glib` 19K ELF

```
json-glib-format -p file.json
```

From package `dev-lang/perl` 4,9K Perl script

(keeps unicode symbols as-is)

```
cat file.json | json_pp
```

From package `dev-libs/yajl` 43K ELF

```
cat file.json | json_reformat
```

From package `dev-lang/python`

(escapes unicode symbols to unreadable \u hex notation, had to replace `python` with `python3` on debian system)

```
python -m json.tool file.json
```